# Yosemite Time Machine not backing up (existing and new backups)

Tags: time-machine, macos

I am having an issue with Time Machine. Since upgrading to Yosemite Time Machine has not been working. I have seen this seems to be a common issue but have not seen reference to my specific case.

I noticed my backup drive (formatted on Yosemite for backups) was not backing up content (although it said it was). I tried formatting the drive and setting it up as a backup drive again but to no avail.

When I run the backup I get the following message for about 5 seconds, Backing up Zero KB of 1.85 TB, and then it disappears saying finishing backup. Obviously the data is not being backed up for some reason.

I have:

- Verified the disk (OK)
- Repaired the disk (OK)
- Formatted the disk (OK)
- Re setup time machine (OK)

I am running:

- Yosemite
- Server 4.0
- SmbUp
- External Drive with work content (to be backed up)
- Backups are set for only the external (other drives are excluded)